# How to make first and last element of a grid different sizes from the other elements?

Tags: html, css, sass, css-grid

I have a grid

```
<div class="grid">
  // a lot of divs
</div>
```

css

```
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(90px, 1fr));
}
```

I need to make the highlighted elements of max-width: 45px. I've tried `grid-template-columns: 45 px repeat(auto-fill, minmax(90px, 1fr)) 45px` but what it does is making first and last column 45px width (but I need the elements). Setting max-width doesn't help, because the first element's line is cut in twice. How can I achieve that? I'm not using flexbox as it can't achieve what I want.
[image]

Comment: have you tried with `:first-child` and `:last-child` selector on your divs inside `.grid` ?

Comment: @Hoargarth, and what should i set to them?

Comment: The grid-template columns merely sets the width of the area where the divs are going to be placed. Just set those divs to `max-width:45px`. - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/ZEBOdge But I suspect this is not what you want.

Comment: You can use `.grid:first-child` and `grid.last-child` to give the styles you need or you can also create two new classes that you can apply in those childs in the html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make all columns 45px wide and then have all items except the first and the last item span two columns, e.g.:

[image]

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(45px, 1fr));
}
.grid div {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.grid div {
  grid-column: span 2;
}
.grid div:first-child, .grid div:last-child {
  grid-column: span 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid" style='max-width:500px'>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's another question, but please could you help me with centering the same case(for example if there are 4 items they will be centered to the left but I need to center, I've tried justify-content\items & align-content\items but it doesn't work)

Answer (score 3):

A similar answer incorporating your additional question on centering the elements on page:

[image: elements centered on page]

Main points:

- replacing 'auto-fill' with `auto-fit`
- using `max-content` instead of '1fr'
- adding `justify-content: center`

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(45px, max-content));
  justify-content: center;
   
}
.grid-item {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.grid-item:first-child, .grid-item:last-child {
  grid-column: span 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">3</div>
  <div class="grid-item">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item">5</div>
  <div class="grid-item">6</div>
  <div class="grid-item">7</div>
  <div class="grid-item">8</div>
</div>
```